# Count Distinct with Quarterly Aggregation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some daily data stored in a Spark dataframe which I aggregate to get a count. I'm doing this like so:

```
start = '2018-11-01'
end = '2021-02-19'

t1 = (
    spark.table('schema.t1')
    .where(sf.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between(start, end))
    .select('yyyy_mm_dd', 'x_id', 'h_id', 'app', 'kpi')
)
```

I then join and aggregate with a second dataframe which contains a list of products.

```
aggregate = (
    t1
    .join(t2, on = ['app', 'kpi'], how = 'left')
    .groupby('x_id', 'product')
    .agg(
        sf.countDistinct('h_id').alias('count_ever')
    )
)
```

The above aggregation allows me to see the distinct count of `h_id` that have used each product since `2018-11-01`, per `x_id`.

I was wondering how could I modify the aggregation to still do `countDistinct()` but between quarter start and end dates as opposed to all time.

So instead of counting ever (`2018-11-01 -> 2021-02-19`) as my code does, I would count these ranges:

```
2018-11-01 -> 2018-12-31
2019-01-01 -> 2019-03-31
2019-04-01 -> 2019-06-30
2019-07-01 -> 2019-09-30
2019-10-01 -> 2019-12-31
2020-01-01 -> 2020-03-31
2020-04-01 -> 2020-06-30
2020-07-01 -> 2020-09-30
2020-10-01 -> 2020-12-31 
2021-01-01 -> 2021-02-19
```

Expected output would be the same that my code produces but with an additional year / quarter grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the quarter as well, using `trunc` on the date:

```
aggregate = (
    t1
    .join(t2, on = ['app', 'kpi'], how = 'left')
    .groupby('x_id', 'product', sf.trunc(sf.to_date('yyyy_mm_dd', 'yyyy_MM_dd'), 'quarter').alias('quarter'))
    .agg(
        sf.countDistinct('h_id').alias('count_ever')
    )
)
```

Comment: I think this only groups by quarter rather than year and quarter but I will give it a go!

Comment: @Someguywhocodes it groups by both year and quarter. The result of `trunc` will be something like `2021-01-01` for today.

Comment: The quarter column is returning null for me. Might be an issue on my side tho so I'll look into a bit more. I'm using Spark 2.2.0 if it makes a difference

Comment: @Someguywhocodes the yyyy_mm_dd column has to be in standard form (yyyy-mm-dd). Is that the case for your real data?

Comment: Real data is `yyyy_mm_dd` so with underscores rather than hyphens

Comment: @Someguywhocodes then you'll need to convert that column to date type first, using `to_date`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Still getting null after that conversion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228969/discussion-between-mck-and-someguywhocodes).